# Load Datetime column in SQL server 2012 using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, ssis

I'm looking to load a transaction file from a flat file to database. the file contain datetime column which is displayed like this "20160307092701" and I want to display it in the database like "2016-03-07-09-27:01" using SSIS.

I choose my database column to be set as smalldatetime and on the source file and I convert it DT_DBTIME but it showing NULL values when I load the data to SQL server. I have tried all the possible date option in SSIS but still showing Null value.

Check the Error in SQL server:

[image: Check the Error in SQL server]

Comment: Maybe you need `2016-03-07 09:27:01`? If you want like this `2016-03-07-09-27:01` the column data type must be `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 3):

The format you show you want cannot use `smalldatetime` because that is not the format of the data type you selected on your destination table. The destination date format would be like `2016-03-07 09:27:00`, but if you want it as `2016-03-07-09-27:01` then you will have to store that as a string in your table.

As well the input value is returning a NULL because SSIS cannot convert that format into a date. You would have to use an expression or Script Task of some sort in order to parse that value out to the end format you want it, before sending it to your destination.

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for your help. I'm have used scrip component to try and convert the string type to datetime.  but I still came across error when perusing the transformation. the code are Convert.ToDateTime(Row.TransactionDate); I could be wrong

Comment: If you add what you tried and any error information you are getting we can provide a bit more help.